# How to troubleshoot odd Google Analytics data that possibly includes Googlebot?

Tags: google-analytics, googlebot

We are a natural foods grocery chain located in Seattle, WA. Our store location pages are among the most viewed pages on our website, including the [locations index page](http://www.pccnaturalmarkets.com/locations/index.php) that serves as a store locator where you can enter your zip code to find the nearest stores.

Beginning with stats for Tuesday, February 3, 2015, I began seeing suspicious behavior that peaked on Friday, February 6 and continues today and appears to only be affecting our store locator page for our "www." hostname (versus our "m." hostname). Specifically, I observed an unusually high number of views where the source was "(direct)". For the vast majority of these direct views, many of the standard dimensions, such as browser, operating system, region, etc, have a value of "(not set)". So far there have been almost 2,800 page views that match this criteria, with about 260 of them being unique (also odd).

When I looked at the Apache access log, I discovered that there were no where near enough requests for the page in question -- even if I included requests where the user agent is identified as Googlebot, bingbot or Yahoo! Slurp.

Thus far, these anomalies have concerned the page without any query parameters. However, as I was reviewing, I discovered another mystery that also began on February 3. There were a lot of requests with the zip code query parameter set to zip codes outside our market area. Again, the standard dimensions were logged as "(not set)". This time when I looked at the server logs, I did find an equivalent number of requests, but the very surprising thing was the majority were from Googlebot! My first thought was that someone was spoofing Googlebot, but by following Google's documented steps for validating, these seemed legit.

For example, On February 6, there were two requests in the server log for "/locations/index.php?zip=66758&radius=5" (this is the zip for Neosho Falls, KS). The user agent for both was logged as "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)". One request was from 66.249.67.61 and the other from 66.249.67.77.

```
host 66.249.67.77
77.67.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-67-77.googlebot.com.

host crawl-66-249-67-77.googlebot.com
crawl-66-249-67-77.googlebot.com has address 66.249.67.77

host 66.249.67.61
61.67.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-67-61.googlebot.com.

host crawl-66-249-67-61.googlebot.com
crawl-66-249-67-61.googlebot.com has address 66.249.67.61
```

And in Google Analytics, there were exactly 2 pages views reported (1 unique) at the same time.

Also odd is that all of these zip code based requests were reporting zero for the number of "Entrances". I then later discovered that these zip code based requests were often the landing pages for the aforementioned suspicious page views with no query parameters.

On February 6, there were only a total of 472 of these zip code requests in Google Analytics, but the server had logged almost 2,000 with Googlebot as the user agent. It appears the bot was running through a long list of zip codes.

I keep thinking to myself there is something obvious I'm missing since Googlebot activity should be excluded from Google Analytics reports. I've [posted](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/rLwIBan7QHA/QZDkAcA-f-YJ) to the Google Analytics product forum with no replies yet.

I should also add that we're using the classic version of the tracking code, which hasn't been edited recently.